# Why is the VII from the natural minor scale not called bVII?

Tags: chord-theory, roman-numerals

In my textbook there is a natural sign in front of the subtonic chord.

Why is the VII chord in minor called "natural" 7 with a natural sign in  front and the diminished chord built on the raised 7 just called vii°?
Shouldn't the natural VII chord from natural minor be called bVII since it is built on a minor 7th interval up from the tonic?

This chord also comes up in major so if it has the same name it makes more sense. Also, if you are going to call VII the natural one because it occurs in the natural minor scale then surely vii° should be called #vii°?

Comment: Glad you brought up VII and vii° both occurring in the same Roman numeral analysis. ...However, now I have a niggling feeling that VI and vi° in minor also get treated in a similar way (e.g. not bVI, not #vi°).

Comment: With that being said, what key was the passage with the ♮VII mention? I'm really starting to think it's a key where the leading tone has a sharp while the subtonic has a natural and therefore one of your questions is moot (e.g. A minor, E minor).

Comment: cant we just use roman numerals in reference to the major scale then? so in minor vi° and vii° need no alterations as they occur on the same major 6th and major 7th intervals as in the major scale? Then if we use a subtonic chord we would have to call that bVII because it is a minor 7th above the tonic note. Of course bVI would refer to the triad built on the min 6th interval of the scale.

Comment: It has nothing to do with any passage, subtonic chords in minor are named with a natural sign arent they?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the flat roman numerals in minor when they aren't needed?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106872/why-the-flat-roman-numerals-in-minor-when-they-arent-needed)

Comment: I know this type of Roman numeral analysis isn’t going anywhere soon but when I went to college 100 years ago we used a different non traditional type of Roman numeral analysis more common to pop and jazz where everything is written literally. All numerals were caps and chord quality was labeled. For example Im instead of i for a minor key.  In the key of C major or minor bVII is Bb, VII is B, III is E, bIII is Eb, etc. This removes all ambiguity and having to learn special rules for non-diatonic chords, minor and modal interchange. It makes life much easier, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention (as is all notation.) In minor keys, Roman numerals are based on the lowered form of the two mutable steps (6 and 7). This (at least in modern notational practice) makes the conventions for Roman numerals identical in major and minor keys; the roman numerals refer to a chord root that agrees with the key signature.

In some Renaissance and Baroque minor-key pieces, the key signature was different from that of the relative major. Usually, a flat signature minor key had one fewer flat but sometimes a sharp signature had one fewer sharp. The practice wasn't consistent.

Often, in analysis, some shortcuts are made for common occurrences. Kosta and Payne often use the harmonic minor as a basis for Roman numeral roots.

Answer (score 0):

In *natural* minor scale notes, note ^7 is a full tone below the root. It gets sharpened when the harmonic or rising melodic comes out to play. Thus it will be called VII, in its 'standard' form. Everything uses the basic major scale notes as the datum point, so it makes sense that ^7 in the relative natural minor is called VII, not ♭VII - which could be construed as  G♭ in key Am.

When we *do* talk about the raised leading note rooted chord in the minor key, then that gets called ♯VII - G♯ in key Am.And since it's then diminshed, it's actually ♯VII°.

Comment: That's weird, I've never actually seen #vii° or #vii°7 before in textbooks or exercise books, ever.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - how would you expect a triad based on the **leading** note of a minor key to be labelled?

Comment: He means that it is usually just vii° and the #is not used

Comment: @armani - I'm actually female, but you get the gist.

Comment: Sorry, will try remember that :)